Mapping Tuple from Native Query Result to DTO in Spring Data JPA
I'm trying to map the results of a native SQL query executed through Spring Data JPA to a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class. The query retrieves data from two related tables: Data and Address.
Here are the details:
Entity Classes:
@Entity
public class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String description;

    private String type;

    private LocalDateTime date;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> addresses;

}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String street;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Data data;

}

DataRepository:
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {
  @Query(value = """
    select d.id, name, type, a.id as addressid, a.street as street from data d inner join address a ON d.id = a.data_id
  """, nativeQuery = true)
  List<Tuple> getDataWithList();
}

This interface defines a custom query named getDataWithList that uses a native SQL query to retrieve data from the Data and Address tables with an inner join.
DTO Class:
public record DataJoinDto(
        Long id,
        String name,
        String type,
        List<AddressDto> addresses
) { }

public record AddressDto(Long id, String street) { }

I want to map the elements in the List returned by the query to instances of the DataJoinDto class. I need to use NATIVE QUERIES.
I've attempted manual mapping, but it's not ideal and easy.
I'm seeking a more efficient and potentially cleaner way to achieve the mapping.

Isn't there alway one address per data? Why do you loop twice over the same collection? If I understand this correctly you get an object by id X and call it dataId the first time then you get the same object by the same id X and call it addressId.

Hi @ValerijDobler, You are right, it is incorrect because that way I have duplicate DTOs at the end. I edit the question now.

@ValerijDobler, I really need to map the tuples to the DTOs. Normally when the Tuple contains simple data, without lists, the mapping is very simple, but in this case, with the List, I don't know how to achieve it and make it efficient.

Do you really need bidirectional mapping Address <-> Data? Usually, you define an aggregate, in this case, a Data object and it assigns the Addresses and is also responsible for persisting it. Or can an Address object live without being assigned to a Data object?
